# UI-Grid Import data feature adds empty lines

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using UI-Grid and populating it with CSV data using import feature:

All works OK when I import data from first time. Issues occurs when I try importing data from a second file (could be same as the first file or a different file). Instead of contents of the second file, I see blank lines appended in the grid. I would ideally expect contents of second file to overwrite the first file OR get appended.

The problem can be easily replicated in UI-Grid's tutorial demo page here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/207_importing_data

How to resolve this issue ?

[image]

[UPDATE]
I see that the issue occurs when Header field has more than one word

Sample CSV File: -->>

```
Name,Gender Specify,Company Name
John Smith,male,TestIcon
Jane Doe,female,FastTrucks
```

I imported this file twice. As "Gender Specify" and "Company Name" both consists of 2 words, they have blank values. Looks like a bug with UI-Grid

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid works fine after I specified the column definitions explicitly in gridOptions.

$scope.columns = [{ field: 'Symbol' }, { field: 'Product Type'}, {field: 'Schedule Amount'}];
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = $scope.columns;